# Any way to make symbolic links from a Mac work on Windows?

Tags: windows, macos, symlink, mklink

We've a development environment where Jenkins runs builds on a Mac Mini (our local build machine), from git commits, then eventually shunts things out to a directory, accessible by both web access, and samba.  The last step is running,

```
ln -s ${GIT_COMMIT} latest
```

Which creates a symbolic link to the build folder of that particular commit.

Unfortunately, on Windows, when accessing via Samba, it falls over at the symlink stage, stating "The directory name is invalid".  This is the same as when you do a Windows mklink to a directory without the "/D" (directory) option.

On windows, both symlinks (created on Mac, or Windows) show up as "SYMLINK", if you dir the folder, whereas if you use the "/D" option, that symlink shows up as "SYMLINKD".  Both show up with the correct view "[${GIT_COMMIT} -> latest]" though.

So what I'm asking is, is there any way to get Windows to be able to understand, process, and follow those symlinks, as in is there some kinda little known flag when you create the symlink?

If that's not possible, the other thing I noticed was that the windows directory symlink "mklink /D" worked on all platforms, *nix, Mac and Windows.  So with that, is there any possible way to create that type of symlink from the Mac?